# MySQL LEFT JOIN filtering rows where NULL

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to return whether a user has favourited an item or not. I have the MySQL statement:

```
SELECT *,`user_choice`.fav FROM `items`
LEFT JOIN `user_choice` ON `user_choice`.item_id = `items`.item_id
```

This returns a full set of results, with `user_choice`.fav equal to 0, 1 or NULL

However, I would like to only show the `user_choice`.fav (whatever that value may be) for a given user, so I have added a `WHERE` statement for that user like so:

```
SELECT *,`user_choice`.fav FROM `items`
LEFT JOIN `user_choice` ON `user_choice`.item_id = `items`.item_id
WHERE `user_choice`.user_id=xx
```

When I add this WHERE statement, it filters out any results from the first statement where `user_choice`.fav is NULL (ie not 1 or 0). How can I get it to return values even when they are NULL

example data:

`items`

### item_id | item_name

1,itemname

2,item2name

3,item3name

`user_choice`

### user_id | item_id | fav

1,1,1

1,3,0

Comment: Your question would be much clearer if you added sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 4):

0, 1 are not considered NULL values, so your WHERE statement is excluding them.  You need to add another OR into your WHERE clause as follows:

```
SELECT *,`user_choice`.fav FROM `items`
LEFT JOIN `user_choice` ON `user_choice`.item_id = `items`.item_id
WHERE `user_choice`.user_id=xx OR `user_choice`.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: will this try and match with the user first, then default to null?

Comment: No, in your question you've asked how to return values even if they are NULL.

Comment: I am trying to return 0 or 1 where the user_id in `user_choice` is equal xx, but if the corresponding `item` and `user` do not exist in `user_choice` I would like to return NULL, where presently it is removing the row

Comment: Try a FULL OUTER JOIN, otherwise you'll need to post some data along with the question.